# How to print the for loop as the last thing in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So here is my function and some info on it:

This function is called by another function, so returning the result1 would print what I want. 
So, in this function, I want to be able to print result1 then the for loop after; although, since I am unable to place the for loop inside the return, it would always print the for loop first, then the returned result1 would be printed next.

Note: Dish_str() is another function, I will include it at the bottom

```
def Restaurant_str(self: Restaurant) -> str:
    result1 = ("Name:     " + self.name + "\n" +
               "Cuisine:  " + self.cuisine + "\n" +
               "Phone:    " + self.phone + "\n" +
               "Menu:    ")
    for i in self.menu:
        print(Dish_str(i))
    return result1 + "\n\n"
```

This is the result:

```
Fried Chicken ($10.00): 1300.0cal
Name:     KFC
Cuisine:  American
Phone:    1112223333
Menu:
```

I want to make it so that the dish would come after the menu.

One way that I attempted to make it work was putting the Dish_str() into the return so it would look like this:

```
return result1 + Dish_str(self.menu) + "\n\n"
```

To which, I'd receive an error that says an attribute error saying that the list does not contain attribute name, even though in the for loop, it was able to work. Then I tried doing simply just Dish_str(self) which gives me a type error that can't concatenate a list.

Another way I tried to make it work was also split the for loop into another function and have the Restaurant_str() call it, but alas, no avail because I realized it was the same exact thing as calling Dish_str() just with another extra function.

Here is the other functions that are calling it and being called on:

```
def Dish_str(self: Dishes) -> str: 
'''Returns a string that represents the dish name, price, and calories'''
result = self.name + " ($" + str("%.2f" % self.price) + "): " + 
         str(self.calories) + "cal"
    return result

def Collection_str(C: list) -> str:
    ''' Return a string representing the collection
    '''
    s = ""
    for r in C:
        s = s + Restaurant_str(r)
    return s
```

I simply print the collection through:

```
print(Collection_str(C))
```

Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything as I wrote this late at night and didn't have time to check in the morning. Thank you for your patience and help in advance.

Comment: `for i in self.menu: result1 += Dish_str(i)` will simply append each item in Dish_str to the string you are returning.

Comment: Ah, I see. I cannot believe I had overlooked something so simple. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the string `dish` to the end of `result1`,  `result1 = result1 + Dish_str(i)`

```
def Restaurant_str(self: Restaurant) -> str:
result1 = ("Name:     " + self.name + "\n" +
           "Cuisine:  " + self.cuisine + "\n" +
           "Phone:    " + self.phone + "\n" +
           "Menu:    ")
for i in self.menu:
    result1 = result1 + Dish_str(i)
return result1 + "\n\n"
```

Would this help?

Comment: Thanks so much. It very much helped. How dumb of me to overlook something so simple as such, haha. Thank you again.